# NSScrollView - pattern background - how to start from top-left corner?

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview

To fill `NSScrollview` with pattern image I use `- (void)setBackgroundColor:(NSColor *)aColor` method where `aColor` is created with `+ (NSColor *)colorWithPatternImage:(NSImage *)image` method. Despite of what `isFlipped` returns for `NSScrollView` and its content view, pattern start repeat from bottom-left corner while I want it to start from top-left corner. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the key here may be that -setBackgroundColor: of the NSScrollView:

> Sets the color of the content view’s
>   background to aColor.

The content view of a NSScrollView is a separate view inside of the NSScrollView.

So, what you will probably need to do is be able to change the isFlipped of the content view of the NSScrollView.

I haven't played around with this yet, so I don't know what problems you may run into.

EDIT: However, it appears your answer may be found here:

[CocoaDev: NSScrollView](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSScrollView)

Look near the bottom of the article.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the method [NSGraphicsContext setPatternPhase:]. [This thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/167158-setpatternphase-woes.html) provides the details. It worked for me.